# ImportError __init__.py, flask

Tags: python, flask, python-import

I'm following this tutorial [Simple Packages](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/packages/)

I have the exact same code as on tutorial except for `import myapp.views` in `__init__.py` I change it to `import views` to pass `no module named myapp.views`. 
but I still get another error in `views.py`:
`no module named app`

Package structure:

```
parent/
  runserver.py
  myapp/
    __init__.py
    views.py
```

runserver code:

```
from myapp import app
app.run(debug=True)
```

`__init__` code:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

import views
```

views code:

```
from myapp import app

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello World!'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `from myapp import app` as the runpath is in the context of `runserver.py`

Comment: try using,`import .views` as it will then match direct path

Comment: Which python version are you using ?

Comment: Your exact code (as it is in the question) is running on my machine. Are you  sure there is some problem ? My python version is 2.7.9 and Flask vers is 0.10.1

Comment: That's my flask version too, I'm using Git Bash terminal to run the code from a vagrant VM can this be the problem? this the way I ran all codes from all tutorials at Udacitys @YashMehrotra

Comment: Which OS is your VM running ?

Comment: gnu/linux @YashMehrotra

Comment: Try running your code on a hosting site like koding.com or pythonanywhere.com

Comment: So I uploaded my files to pythonanywhere.com but got the same error message, also reinstalled python, tried running the code with IDLE and vagrant VM but still getting the same error @YashMehrotra